# How would pressing backspace 28 times break Grub2

Tags: security, grub2

I just came across this article about how pressing backspace 28 times on the grub screen.

Since most mainstream media just says this happens, I've been unable to find anything that explains how it could possibly happen.

Does anybody know why pressing backspace 28 times would break Grub2? Is it a memory thing?

Answer (score 1):

On the original post, you have a good explanation:! http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2015-8370-Grub2-authentication-bypass.html
The bug is caused by an interger underflow which is not checked.